# What is the function of the word "possible" in "interpret this information in the quickest way possible"?

Tags: word-usage, parsing, postpositive-adjectives

> This is where most people are impeded from being an iconoclast.
> For example, when confronted with information streaming from the eyes,
> the brain will interpret this information in the quickest way **possible**.

What is the function of the word "possible" in the last sentence?
Is it resultative adjectives?
If not, what is the function of this word?

Comment: I don't know where you got this text from, but I'd bet any money it wasn't written by a native Anglophone. Native speakers would more likely express that first sentence as *This is what prevents most people from being iconoclasts* (except ***iconoclast*** isn't all that common anyway, so perhaps ***...from attacking traditional beliefs***).

Comment: I don't see anything "resultative" about the cited context, so personally, I'd say ***possible*** is just an "intensifying" adjective modifying ***the quickest way***, which itself is part of the adverbial element starting with ***in***, that modifies the verb ***interpret***. Where *the quickest way possible = the quickest possible way = the **very** quickest way*.

Comment: I've got it from Cambridge IELTS 9 Academic Reading test 2 passage 3 paragraph 3. For example, https://practicepteonline.com/ielts-reading-test-2/. I doubted why did they put the word 'possible' in that position? I didn't know what the function of the word was. So I tried my best and concluded that the word was 'resultative adjectives' because it was behind nouns.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
I've done some research. This is what I've found.
https://www.englishgrammar.org/attributive-adjectives-nouns/
https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/postpos.htm#:~:text=Adjectives%20in%20the%20first%20position,Instead%2C%20they%20follow%20a%20verb.
Do you think this is a good explanation?

`Postpositive adjectives are commonly found together with superlative, attributive adjectives: the shortest route possible, the worst conditions imaginable, the best hotel available`

Comment: I can't find the *exact* text from your comment in that link, but basically, I'd say ***Yes**!* I think you did an excellent bit of research there! Note - although the postpositive *can* be used after superlative, [it doesn't *have* to be.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+best+available+man%2Cthe+best+man+available&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20best%20available%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20best%20man%20available%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20best%20available%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20best%20man%20available%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

As you've already explained in the comments, "possible" is a [postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective), here modifying "the quickest way".

From wikipedia:

> Certain adjectives are used fairly commonly in postpositive position. Present and past participles exhibit this behavior, as in all those entering should ..., one of the men executed was ..., but at will this can be considered to be a verbal rather than adjectival use (a kind of reduced relative clause). Similar behavior is displayed by many adjectives with the suffix -able or -ible (e.g. the best room available, the only decision ***possible***, the worst choice imaginable, the persons liable).